# Should I filter user password before storing them in database?

Tags: database, security, passwords

It is recommended to never trust the user and filter all input before storing them in the database, to avoid sql injections and such.

What about user password ? Should I perform any kind of sanitization before storing them ? If I do so, user typing they password to log in might not match a sanitized version.

( Password are encrypted before being stored).

What's the best practice?

Comment: **Do not** store plain passwords in a database.. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is recommended to never trust the user and filter all input before storing them in the database, to avoid sql injections and such.

No, not at all. It's recommended to avoid SQL injection by using prepared statements, and to avoid HTML/script injection by properly escaping special characters when displaying data.

> Should I perform any kind of sanitization before storing them

No, you shouldn't. And you shouldn't encrypt passwords either. You should instead salt and hash them, using a strong cryptographic algorithm like Bcrypt.

Comment: Bcrypt is a secure method, is not just a salted hash, it is an iterative method and requires ~100ms of compute time

Answer (score 0):

> Should I perform any kind of sanitization before storing them ...

In addition to JB Nizet's answer with respect to storage, you *should* filter them prior to accepting one. Consider, ***Password1*** meets NIST security requirements, but its also on [nearly?] every attacker's Top N password list. Obviously, you don't want an attacker to be able to use their favorite password list against you.

The lists themselves can be rather large. I've seen sizes of 10,000, 100,000, and 10 million. The lists can be compressed down to 20KB or 40KB using a Bloom filter. Then, when the user selects a password, check the candidate password against the filter. The Bloom filter will produce some false positives, but that's OK. Simply ask the user to select a different password.

Here's a GitHub with a 10,000-password list: [noloader/Password-Lists](https://github.com/noloader/Password-Lists). Another list is available at [danielmiessler/SecLists](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords). Also see Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security, Chapter 6: Passwords](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf).